# apt-proxy not working for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apt

After upgrading client machine from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, They are unable to connect & fetch updates & package installation from apt-proxy machine. Please find attached [image]. Please reply if you have / find solution.

Comment: paste your proxy conf  file here

Comment: I have entered ` Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.174.131:3142/apt-cacher";` in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy file as per the documentation from [Apt-Cacher](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher)

Comment: try using `Acquire::http::Proxy "192.168.174.131:3142";

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](http://pifuge.com/ubuntu/fEUm-regexp-config-var-for-apt-cacher-to-allow-repo-files-for-16-04-clients-metadata) worked for me:

In Edit the *apt-cacher.conf* file on server:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf
```

Uncomment the "*ubuntu_release_names*" and replace with this:

```
ubuntu_release_names = dapper, edgy, feisty, gutsy, hardy, intrepid, jaunty, karmic, lucid, maverick, natty, oneiric, precise, quantal, raring, saucy, trusty, utopic, vivid, wily, xenial
```

Uncomment the "*index_files_regexp*" and replace with this:

```
index_files_regexp = ^(?:Index(?:\.bz2)?|(?:Sources|Packages|release)(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)?|Release(?:\.gpg)?|InRelease|Contents-(?:[a-z]+-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.gz|(?:srclist|pkglist)\.[a-z-]+\.bz2|Translation-[a-z]{2,3}(?:_[A-Z]{2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?)?(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz|\.lzma)?|Components-[a-z0-9]+\.yml(?:\.gz|\.bz2)?|icons-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.tar(?:\.gz)?)$
```

Save the changes and exit.

> ctrl+o, ctrl+x

Restart *apt-cacher*

```
sudo service apt-cacher restart
```

Finally on the computer with Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```